# Compound Queries in Amazon CloudSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I want to use group by result from AWS cloud search.

```
 user | expense | status 
  1   | 1000    | 1 
  1   | 300     | 1 
  1   | 700     | 2 
  1   | 500     | 2 
  2   | 1000    | 1 
  2   | 1200    | 3 
  3   | 200     | 1 
  3   | 600     | 1 
  3   | 1000    | 2
```

Above are my table structure, I want total count of expense for all user. Expected Answer is-

```
{ user:1,expense_count:2500},{user:2,expense_count:2200 },{user:3,expense_count:1800 }
```

I want `GROUP BY` the *user* column, and it should count the total expenses of the respective user.

Comment: How you got the result, through boto, aws cli, or other tools? Second, if you can export the result as json format, you should be fine to deal it with other exist tools.

Answer (score 2):

There is no (easy) way to do this in CloudSearch, which is understandable when you consider that your use case is more like a SQL query and is not really what I would consider a *search*. If what you want to do is look up users by userId and sum their expenses, then a search engine is the wrong tool to use.

CloudSearch isn't meant to be used as a datastore; it should return minimal information (ideally just IDs), which you then use to retrieve data. Here is a blurb about it from the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/retrieving-data.html):

> You should only store document data in the search index by making
>   fields return enabled when it's difficult or costly to retrieve the
>   data using other means. Because it can take some time to apply
>   document updates across the domain, you should retrieve critical data
>   such as pricing information by using the returned document IDs instead
>   of returned from the index.